# i am getting an error - Subquery returned more than 1 value. What is wrong with my query

Tags: sql-server

what is wrong with my query . its giving an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
Select top 1 name, 
            email, 
            [password]
FROM [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[user] 
WHERE id = (
    Select userid 
    FROM [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[EmployerUser] 
    WHERE empusertype=1 and employerid=96
    )
```

Comment: What is this query **supposed** to do?

Comment: There is more than one record returned from the [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[EmployerUser] table with a empusertype of 1 and an employerid of 96...I suggest you change your query to a JOIN.

Comment: apart from other suggesation,you can also use top 1 in subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `IN` keyword rather than `=`

```
Select top 1  name, email, password FROM [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[user]
 WHERE id IN (Select userid FROM [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[EmployerUser]
 WHERE empusertype=1 and employerid=96)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query

```
Select userid 
FROM [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[EmployerUser] 
WHERE empusertype=1 and employerid=96
```

has returned more than 1 element. If you are sure that these records have equal `userid` field then use `IN` operator instead of `=`. Also try this :

```
Select distinct userid 
FROM [MyPeople_DataVersion2].[dbo].[EmployerUser] 
WHERE empusertype=1 and employerid=96
```

It returns unique `userid`, so you wont get equal ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1
        name
       ,email
       ,password
FROM    MyPeople_DataVersion2.dbo.[user] usr
JOIN    MyPeople_DataVersion2.dbo.EmployerUser empUsr
ON      usr.id = empUsr.userid
WHERE   empUsr.empusertype = 1
        AND empUsr.employerid = 96
```